# Does learning a new data structure have an impact on the structure and efficiency of the brain?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic

Since there are some very efficient data structures what is the probability that learning a new data structure makes our brain work more efficiently? Or are all data structures actually extracted from brain structures that have been around before programming even existed? Is this the right site for this type of questions? Which tags should i use it with?

Answer (score 1):

The neurons in a brain are structured like a directed graph. Many data structures can also be viewed as special cases of such a directed graph. So your analogy between data structures and brain structures is not too far-fetched. There are structures in the brain that resemble linked lists or trees, however these are far from ideal implementations like in a digital computer.

Trying to answer your first question, sure, learning data structures does affect your brain, like any kind of learning does. Otherwise it would not be learning. But it is safe to say that learning about binary trees will not create binary trees in your brain :).

In my opinion, this is the right site for your question, but I know that many people here see this differently. Actually I am a bit surprised that this question has not been closed yet.